# Is it possible to access Chef in Ruby outside of a cookbook/recipe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am looking to have a ruby script on my Chef workstation that would use the Chef ruby gem and would be able to access data bags on its own, without being a cookbook or recipe.

Are you able to do this?

Comment: There exist multiple API clients, including [chef-api](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-api) and [ridley](https://github.com/berkshelf/ridley) that should allow you to access data bags.

Comment: Copy this down to an answer, it is correct :) chef-api is the right thing to use for complex scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist multiple API clients, including [chef-api](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-api) and [ridley](https://github.com/berkshelf/ridley) that should allow you to access data bags.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Stephen's answer/comment, check out `knife exec` for simple one-liners. It is usually easier to get going than chef-api.